# window.top.close() not working

Tags: visualforce, javascript

In my visualforce page, I'm trying to close the current tab in "OnComplete" function in apex:actionFunction. I tried using both **window.close()** and **window.top.close()**. But nothing worked out.

Any idea on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close),

> ... for security reasons, scripts are no longer allowed to close windows they didn't open.

So the question here would be... is your window open with a script? if not, then you can't close it with javascript.

A longer answer was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761241/window-close-and-self-close-do-not-close-the-window-in-chrome)

Comment: This visualforce page is opened on a custom button click from the record detail page.

Comment: @sfdcOwl, please add in your original post the code you have so far (related to the window.close() so we can see what could be wrong ;)

Comment: My bad !!! After modifying the code, I didn't click on the custom button to re-test it. I just tried by refreshing the vf page. It's working now.. Thanks @Sergio for your answer